# .NET 4.0 vs 3.5 performance

Tags: c#, .net, performance

Does anybody know if .NET 4 is more efficient?

From following simple snippet it seems to be slower. It took around 630ms using .NET 4.0 and 530ms using .NET 3.5 SP1.

What results do you get? Any suggestions? I am considering converting my application to .NET 4.0 but these results are putting me off.

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++)
        {
            string s = "asdfx54545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454adsf4asdf";
            int j = s.IndexOf("asdf");
            s.IndexOf("asdf", j);


            s = s + "zxcv";
            s = s + "gtjiortege";
        }

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: There are better things to be put off by than contrived test cases like the one shown here. Maybe if you show an actual piece of code from your application where the bottleneck occurs...

Comment: Are you talking about 0.1 seconds out of 60 seconds? That's less than 0.2%. Not really significant or certain. If no, what is the 100 ms to be compared to?

Comment: by 1 minute I mean that the test overall took me 1minute to complete ...did not spend days on it. Test took around 630ms using .NET 4.0 and 530ms using .NET 3.5 SP1

Comment: There are quite some changes in the CLR but your test is not very good as the others have commented.

Comment: If need to count every ms your app spends on computing, maybe you'd be better off using C++ instead. Newer framework may be somewhere slower, somewhere faster, somewhere just more fool-proof, but performance isn't the decisive factor when upgrading onto a newer .NET framework. There are much more important factors you should think of when deciding, like - do I need these new features, so I can justify the time for migration? Or maybe - can my app be actually run on client computers or are there any compatibility issues involved?

Comment: What's the point of this code? Do you have some real world code that you would like to discuss?

Answer (score 6):

This issue was [reported](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/616367/framework-4-string-indexof-string-string#details) and [fixed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2467309).

Rather than install the hotfix, a workaround is to specify Oridinal as the StringComparison type if you don't need a culture specific comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Yes .Net 4.0 is more efficient than 3.5. In my case I had a numerical algorithm that had an exponent function in a loop. I was able to deterministically reproduce a ~2x speed up. It looks like the primary wins are coming from the CRT, not the JIT. The 8.0/3.5 CRT was using x87 floating point instructions, but the 10.0/4.0 CRT is using SSE. The JIT uses the CRT for the Log/ Log10 and Exp calls. It seems like the SSE instructions used by the C runtime are the primary source of the wins although the JIT-ed code was better too.